# In python, how to calculate how many days a particular date exceeds the "base date"?

Tags: python, nlp

I have a set of time series data like `[2015-01-23,2015-01-04,2015-01-03]`. I want to process the data like this. I set a `base date` `2015-01-01` and calculate how many days the date exceed the `base date`. For example `2015-01-23` exceeds `2015-01-01` for 22 days and `2015-01-04` exceeds `2015-01-01` for 3 days and `2015-01-03` exceeds `2015-01-01` for 2 days. Then I can get the vector [22,3,2] and I can scale the vector to `0~1` like`[1,0.05,0]`. But I don't know how to implement my thought because the length of month is not fixed. Like the date `2015-07-2`, how could I calculate the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) built-in library.

```
from datetime import datetime

base_date = "2015-01-01"
data = ["2015-01-23", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-03"]
format = "%Y-%m-%d"

base = datetime.strptime(base_date, format)
diff = [(datetime.strptime(d, format) - base).days for d in data]
# diff == [22, 3, 2]
```

Comment: @deathlee Welcome to Python. :)

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it worked for you so other users will know!